# Where does SQL Server get estimated number of rows for when AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS is off

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

Where does SQL Server get the Estimated Number of Rows when you have `AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS` turned off?

Here is an example:

Setup experiment:

```
USE master;
GO

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'TestDatabase')
BEGIN
    ALTER DATABASE TestDatabase SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
    DROP DATABASE TestDatabase;
END

GO

CREATE DATABASE TestDatabase;

GO

ALTER DATABASE TestDatabase SET AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS OFF;

GO

USE TestDatabase;

GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TestTable;

GO

CREATE TABLE TestTable
(
    Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName VARCHAR(50),
    LastName VARCHAR(50)
);
```

**Please view the edit for the updated code**

Experiment:

Insert 200 rows:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO TestTable Values('Test', 'Blah')
GO 200
```

Click `Display Estimated Execution Plan` when
highlighting the query below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TestTable 
WHERE LastName = 'blah';
```

It gives me an estimated # row of 200.

Run the below query again:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO TestTable Values('Test', 'Blah')
GO 200
```

Once again click `Display Estimated Execution Plan` when
highlighting the query below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TestTable 
WHERE LastName = 'blah';
```

It gives me an estimated # rows of 400.

Now I run query instead of getting estimates

```
SELECT * 
FROM TestTable 
WHERE LastName = 'blah';
```

Now I insert another 200 rows

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO TestTable Values('Test', 'Blah')
GO 200
```

Once again click `Display Estimated Execution Plan` when
highlighting the query below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TestTable 
WHERE LastName = 'blah';
```

It once again gives me an estimated # row of 400 instead of 600 rows.

So I run

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO TestTable Values('Test', 'Blah')
GO 10000
```

Once again click `Display Estimated Execution Plan` when
highlighting the query below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TestTable 
WHERE LastName = 'blah';
```

Gives man an estimated plan of 400 rows instead of 10,600.

So it appears if you get the estimated number of rows before running the query, it will give you the total number of rows in the table.  Once you run the query, it gives you the total number of rows on the table before running the query.

So where exactly is SQL Server getting this number from?

**---EDIT 1: I got my results wrong, sorry about the confusion---**

When I got the above estimates yesterday, I changed my experiment to `AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS ON` to test that behavior and didn't realize it was still on. Sorry about the confusion.

So let me show my screenshots with `AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS OFF`:

- I start with a new database and a new table with `AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS OFF`.
- I insert 200 rows
- Click `Display Estimated Execution Plan` when
  highlighting the query below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TestTable 
WHERE LastName = 'blah';
```

[image]

- Estimates are

  - `Estimated Number of Rows to be Read` is 200 rows
  - `Estimated Number of Rows for All Executions` is 14.142 (which is 200.000^.50).
- I insert another 200 rows
- Click `Display Estimated Execution Plan` again for the above query
  [image]
- Estimates are

  - `Estimated Number of Rows to be Read` is 400 rows
  - `Estimated Number of Rows for All Executions` is 20 (which is 400.000^.50).
- Now I run the above query and get 400 rows as expected.
- I insert 200 rows
- Click `Display Estimated Execution Plan` again for the above query
  [image]
- Estimates are

  - `Estimated Number of Rows to be Read` is 400 rows
  - `Estimated Number of Rows for All Executions` is 20 (which is 400.000^.50).
- I insert 10000 rows
- Estimates are

  - `Estimated Number of Rows to be Read` is 400 rows
  - `Estimated Number of Rows for All Executions` is 20 (which is 400.000^.50).
- Do a statistics update:

```
UPDATE STATISTICS TestTable;
```

- Estimates are the same even after the stat update

  - `Estimated Number of Rows to be Read` is 400 rows
  - `Estimated Number of Rows for All Executions` is 20 (which is 400.000^.50).

So it appears once you run a query, the rows that are used to calculate the estimates are locked-in even after doing a stat update.  This seems really bad.

- The question is, why does it use the locked-in rows after you run a query instead of using the current number of rows on the table?
- Is this row count stored in a DMV to view?

**---End of EDIT 1---**

Comment: And generated execution plan will contain: Clustered Index/Index/Table Scan. Most likely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suggest never setting `AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS` to `OFF` so hopefully this question is just for academic interest.

SQL Server knows the table cardinality (number of rows in the table) as this is held in table metadata independent of statistics. When you say " estimated # rows of 200" etc are you referring to "estimated number of rows to be read"?

As there is no index on `LastName` and it has to scan the whole table to find rows matching the `WHERE` clause this will be the same number as table cardinality. No cardinality estimator model will assume that 100% of those rows will match `LastName = 'blah'` though. For 200 rows in the table I got an estimate of 53 with QUERY_OPTIMIZER_COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL_110 and 14 (`SQRT(200)`) with all later ones.

Either way this is just based on a guessed proportion that will match though as (in the absence of any column statistics or constraints) there is nothing else that can be used to base this number on.

[image]

When you generate an estimated execution plan this is not stored in the plan cache. When you actually run it the plan is cached. So this is why you see estimates of "rows read" in line with actual table cardinality when all you have done so far is generate estimated plans.

> It gives me an estimated # rows of 400.
>
> Now I run query instead of getting estimates

You executed the query when the table had 400 rows and this added the execution plan to the cache (complete with 400 row estimate) - so future executions can use this cached plan.

Once the plan is in the cache you are then dependent on if number of modified rows triggers an optimality based recompile and you get a new execution plan or if it is under the threshold to just use the cached plan.

Usually adding 10,200 rows to a 400 row table would be way in excess of what is required to cross the "Recompilation Threshold" and trigger an optimality based compile. I assume it does not happen in this case as no statistics were ever used in the plan so it can not ever deem these statistics as being stale.

Comment: Yes, this is only for academic purposes.  I also updated my post because I did state the wrong numbers.  Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: @null_pointer  - that doesn't change anything in my answer. With the new cardinality estimator you get `sqrt(table_cardinality)`. This is just a guess by the cardinality estimator as to the selectivity of a single equality predicate with unknown statistics

Comment: And the reason why the number is locked in at cardinality of 400 is explained in the answer (that's when the plan is cached). RE: "This seems really bad." - yep don't do that then. If you are going to turn off auto creation of stats globally on the database you can expect bad cardinality estimates. You could add an `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` hint to get it to recompile every execution and take into account table cardinality but this will still end up with the same plan in this case

Comment: It's not doing an sqrt(table_cardinality) test.  It's `rows^.50`.  So in the example where there are 400 rows, the number is 20.  `SELECT POWER(400, .5)`.  The problem is, once you do a query, the rows are locked in.

Comment: SQRT and power 0.5 are the same thing so I don't see your point? And in this case it is a full scan and  the `rows` is the same as the table cardinality compiled into the plan. Which you see when selecting the index scan operator and looking at the properties

Comment: And I've told you why the rows are locked in.  "Doctor, it hurts when I do this."
"Then don't do that then!”

Comment: Ah, you're correct.  It is because it's in the query cache.  I didn't think about that, which I should have.  You're also right, SQRT and POWER would be the same.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @null_pointer - the table cardinality when the plan was compiled is shown here by the way https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzDsV.png - as it is a full scan this is equal to estimated rows read - then estimated rows returned for this predicate is sqrt of that with new cardinality estimator

Answer (score 1):

When AUTO CREATE STATISTICS is disabled, SQL Server employs a "cardinality estimator" to estimate the number of rows that will be returned by a query.

The cardinality estimator makes this estimate based on a number of factors, including the data types and distributions of the columns in the table, the specific predicates used in the query, and any available statistics.

In your example, it appears that the estimator is estimating the total number of rows in the table rather than the specific predicate in the query ("LastName = 'blah'").

This is most likely due to the table's lack of statistics, which would normally be used to more accurately estimate the number of rows.